# integrating google login to website with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, oauth

Please accept my apology if my question has a simple answer. I'm trying to add a functionality to login through google account with `PHP` and `OAuth 2.0`. I tried this on a simple login page and its working fine.

Now, I have a page of recipe where user can give their comment. Page URL is something like this `mysite.com/recipe-123-recipename`. I changed URL through `.htaccess`. Original link is `mysite.com/single_recipe.php?id=123&title=recipename`.

There is a option of redirect URL in google API console and it is optional so I left it blank. Every time I try to use script i get redirect URL mismatched error.

I just need to know how can I set redirect URL like `single_recipe.php?id=123&title=recipename` so user get back to this page? or I need to change the script? I have added facebook login in same page and it is working great.

Please guide me I tried everything but no luck so far.

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app ?

Comment: I found it myself, created callback script file then redirect to the original page. As i mentioned in my post it was a simple answer.